# Code crashes when inserting a macro into a `\label` and `protecting` the macro doesn't fix

Tags: macros, xstring

This code crashes because I'm including the macro `tmp` into the `label` command.    Reading this forum, especially [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) , I thought that the `\protect` I put in front of `\tmp` should fix the problem, but it doesn't.         Could somebody please explain how to get it to work?     Thanks very much for any suggestions

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\def\tmp{fig:\StrBefore{file.png}{.}}
\tmp
\begin{figure}
\caption{nothing}
\label{\protect\tmp}
%\label{\tmp}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When it comes to processing file-paths and/or filenames it is always good to know whether folder-names/directory-names/filenames/filename-extensions with unbalanced curly braces and/or hashes can play a rôle. E.g., something like `filen#{.ex}` is a valid filename with filename-base `filen#{` and filename-extension `ex}` in some file-systems.  ... It is also good to know whether expansion of macros shall take place when obtaining tokens that form file-paths/filenames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use the ability of `xstring` to store the result of the extraction in a macro.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\StrBefore{file.png}{.}[\tmp]
\edef\tmp{fig:\tmp}
\tmp
\begin{figure}
\caption{nothing}
\label{\tmp}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All three suggestions work, I accepted this one just because I like the `xstring` package and all it does, i.e., hysteresis.     Thanks to all

Answer (score 5):

The macros of `xstring` are not, generally, expandable, which is needed here.  Thus, I change over to `listofitems`, which produces expandable results.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\setsepchar{.}
\readlist\fileroot{file.png}
\edef\tmp{fig:\fileroot[1]}
\tmp
\begin{figure}
\caption{nothing}
\label{\tmp}
\end{figure}

I refer to figure \ref{fig:file}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's a version that doesn't even need `listofitems`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand\fileroot[1]{\filerootaux#1.\relax}
\def\filerootaux#1.#2\relax{#1}
\begin{document}
\edef\tmp{fig:\fileroot{file.png}}
\tmp
\begin{figure}
\caption{nothing}
\label{\tmp}
\end{figure}

I refer to figure \ref{fig:file}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `\label` should be something that eventually becomes a string of characters, but `\StrBefore` eventually becomes *instructions to print some characters*, which is a very different thing.

It's simpler, unless your file names can have multiple periods in their names.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stripext}[1]{\strip@ext#1.\@nil}
\def\strip@ext#1.#2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\stripext{file.png}
\label{\stripext{file.png}}

\stripext{filenoext}
\label{\stripext{filenoext}}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to use a macro with delimited arguments. If we do `\stripext{file.png}`, we get

```
\strip@ext file.png.\@nil
```

and the macro `\strip@ext` uses as `#1` whatever comes along until the first `.`; in this case it is `file`.

In the case of `\stripext{filenoext}`, we get

```
\strip@ext filenoext.\@nil
```

and things are good as well. In the first case `#2` is `png.`, in the second case it is empty; but the second argument is simply thrown away.

The `.aux` file from the code above will contain

```latex
\relax
\newlabel{file}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{filenoext}{{}{1}}
```

so you see it's as expected.